# U28E570D at 60Hz

Tags: display, hdmi

I have this: iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015) and this monitor here

https://www.amazon.it/Samsung-U28E590D-Monitor-Ultra-Display/dp/B01LZ882YU/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1514472088&sr=1-1&th=1

I connected it via thunderbolt and https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B06WWPZRFH/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

the monitor works but I'd like to know how I could reach 60Hz, for now it only goes at 30Hz.

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of the adapter you linked on Amazon, the adapter only supports 4K at 30Hz. You would need a different adapter to reach 60Hz, like this one: [4k 60Hz mDP-HDMI adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00S0BWR2K).

Comment: but it says: Transmits both audio and video from computer or tablet to HDTV display; Supports video resolutions up to 3840x2160 (Ultra HD) at 60 Hz and flawless audio pass-thru for uncompressed digital 7.1, 5.1 or 2 channels.

Comment: @sathia It does say that in the general description at the top, but if you scroll down to the bottom to the more in-depth description, it says: It can support displays of up to 3840x2160 @ 30 Hz HDTV or 4096x2160 @ 24 Hz PC graphics and is ideal for your office, home entertainment display, conference rooms, and more.

Comment: sneaky ******* so, while we are at it, what should I buy to be happy?

Comment: @sathia I would try the one I linked in my answer (it looks less sketchy - and try to return the other one to Amazon, if possible).

Comment: thank you very much, will definitely return to amazon as I got it today. cheers

Comment: so, I got one of the fancy plugs and a fancy hdmi2 cable, still no joy :(